# How to make workspaces joined as extended desktop?

Tags: workspaces, desktop-environments

I'm working with very wide windows that are longer than my screen width.

When I'm in my office I use two monitors (laptop + external monitor) and such windows are spreaded over this extended desktop.
When I'm using my laptop only and I move the wide window behind the edge of workspace 1, part of it disapears, but does not appear in workspace 2.

I believe there is should be a feature that joins workspaces and makes a sort of extended desktop, but I did not find it. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

I will appreciate any suggestion.
Thank you!

Comment: What environment are you using? Unity 2d? Unity 3d? GNOME? KDE?

Comment: @dobey
GNOME classic (No effects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with `GNOME Classic (no effects)` because it uses `metacity` as the window manager, which uses actual workspaces, and not viewports, as `compiz` does. I don't think there is any way to do that with metacity either. If however, you switch to using compiz, either by using GNOME Classic with effects, or the standard Ubuntu session with Unity (3d), then you will get the behavior you desire.

You can use compiz as the window manager, and simply turn off the extra effects which are enabled by default, in the configuration, as well; if they are annoying for you.

Comment: It works with GNOME Classic with effects.
Thanks a lot!